# Preview post in vbb forum by ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbulletin

I want to write a small client-side script for personal use only, the goal is to preview a post, before actually submit it to a vbb forum. Ajax was the first thing comes to my mind. After doing some researchs, I find two ways that works in my target forum, but don't know which is better?

1. [POST] action=update send to url=editpost.php. Response is a really small xml file.
2. [POST] action=reply send to url=newreply.php. Response is a bigger html file.
   If it's just for the sake of that forum, which way is better? The first method actually updates an old post, so server's database must have been updated. I don't know sending a (not much) bigger file and updating database, which is more troublesome?

Btw, if you know something relevant, or a better approach then I'm really glad to hear.